# JDL: UndeclaredEntityException

Tags: jhipster

I am prototyping my database with [jdl](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/) and I am loving the simplicity of it. The problem is the documentation is a little light and I am getting this error:
`UndeclaredEntityException: In the relationship between Room and Pictures, Pictures is not declared.`

Here's the code:

```
...

entity Room {
    RoomId Integer required,
    RoomName String,
    SquareFootage Integer,
    HasRefrigirator Boolean,
    PrivateBathroom Boolean
}

entity Picture {
    Picture Integer required,
    Url String
}
...

relationship OneToMany {
    Room to Pictures{RoomId},
    ....
}
```

I am not sure what this means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem.

```
relationship OneToMany {
    Room to Pictures{RoomId},
    ....
}
```

Change `Pictures` to `Picture`

Also please follow below thread of github regarding this issue :

https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-uml/issues/172

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you.